# A group of order 65 is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra

How am I going to show that a group, using its order, is nilpotent?
For example, a group of order $65$ is nilpotent.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to focus *precisely* on nilpotency, Andreas's answer shows such a group is in fact the direct product of its Sylow subgroups. In the present case it turns out pretty trivial as that product is abelian, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [Sylow's theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems).

You consider in your group $G$ a $13$-Sylow group $T$, which is of course cyclic. You know that the number of $13$-Sylow subgroups is $\lvert G : N_{G}(T) \rvert$, so it divides $5$. But the number of such subgroups is also $\equiv 1 \pmod{13}$, so the number must be $1$, and $T$ is unique and thus normal.

Do the same for a Sylow $5$-subgroup $F$, which is also cyclic, and turns also to be normal with a similar argument. Now $G \cong T \times F$ is abelian, actually cyclic.